# C# - Reading a CSV file in a folder within a current project

Tags: c#, csv, visual-studio-2022

Newbie trying to read a CSV file in Visual Studio 2022.  I can read this file from my own desktop OK but when trying to access it within the folder below I get an Illegal characters in path.  Could someone please tell me the correct path to access this by?

Screen shots and code provided below:

```
namespace ReadDataFromCSV{
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string filePath = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\kirst\source\repos\ReadDataFromCSV\ReadDataFromCSV\CSV_files\TestCountries.csv");
       // string filePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"CSV_files\TestCountries.csv");
      //  string[] files = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
        {
            try
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))

                {
                    string line;
                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

}

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Code and errors]

Thanks!

Kirsty

Comment: fwiw, don't post screenshots of code or errors in the future. The formatted text just above the screenshots is the expected way to share your code here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `filePath` variable initialization assigns it the **entire contents** of the file rather than just the path, so when using it to open a `StreamReader` you get unexpected results.

To fix this, change the line where it's created from this:

```
string filePath = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\kirst\source\repos\ReadDataFromCSV\ReadDataFromCSV\CSV_files\TestCountries.csv");
```

To this:

```
string filePath = @"C:\Users\kirst\source\repos\ReadDataFromCSV\ReadDataFromCSV\CSV_files\TestCountries.csv";
```

---

This also seems to be practice/learning code, so I won't look too deeply into specific methods, but I will say I personally would tend to use `File.ReadLines()` (**not** `File.ReadAllLines()`) in place of the `StreamReader` here. I would also tend to use either the built-in [`TextFieldParser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser?view=net-7.0) or a dedicated CSV library from NuGet. I would **not** want to use anything like `string.Split()` for handling CSV data.